# Cant run a code in vscode, instead of showing it to me in the terminal section, it sends me to the output section

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a noob in computer programming, today i installed vscode to learn python, everything was right, i run short and simple lines of code installed some extensions, but i dont know what happened, I'm not sure if i changed some configuration but when i try to run little lines of code (with the button) instead of running it and showing it to me in the "terminal section", it sends me to the "output" section and it just says that the code already run and its done.

[image]

Do somebody knows how to solve it please, it really makes me sad that i just ruined this program because its my first day and this already screw it.
As you can see in the picture, i run the code and it shows off something different in the output section, i wrote that but later changed it. It seem like it runs the file but only when i save it. :(

Comment: You need to save your Python file before running it to get the latest output results.

Comment: I would expect the output to be right where you're seeing it, in the output section. I wouldn't expect the output from running your program via VSCode to show up in the Terminal section.  You should only see results there when you type something at the command prompt in that section.

Comment: Your code file probably does need to be saved before changes will take affect, but most IDEs will do a Save for you when you do Run and haven't saved something.  That may be something you have to enable in the Preferences or something like that.  I don't use VSCode, so I can't comment on it specifically.  I strongly recommend PyCharm.

Comment: can you just close the output window and then press ctrl+` [backtick] (the character before 1 and above tab on your keyboard)

Comment: and yes you need to save your file before running it, or you can enable autosave. read more here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save

Comment: "it really makes me sad that i just ruined this program because its my first day and this already screw it" you will face many, many harder challenges than this in the course of your programming career/hobby. Software development is *hard*, and it's *ok to struggle with it*. Especially at first. Don't be discouraged! If it were easy they wouldn't pay people to do it.

Comment: You don't have a Folder open so no launch configurations, tour file is not saved, read the python docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python and do the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You must save the file to get the new output everytime.

**For running code in Terminal with the button -**
It looks like you are using **Code Runner** vscode extension. Which by default uses Output section to show output and cannot take input. You can change this behavior of that extension by pressing `ctrl + ,` and going into vscode settings. Then just search `code runner run in terminal` You'll see an option to enable *Run in Terminal* feature turn that on. [image: Image reference]